# slow ElasticSearch query while using term aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I am having around 20million data in ES, If I only query

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                  "term": {
                      "uniqueId": "10921152912079"
                  }
              }
          ]
       
    }
  }
```

Then I am getting results in 1ms, but If I add aggregation on this filtered data, then it is taking around 2sec to execute the query

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                  "term": {
                      "uniqueId": "10921152912079"
                  }
              }
          ]
       
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "raf": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "randomId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So my question is, If I am aggregating on queried result (max 10 document), why aggregation is so slow that its taking 2sec? Or is it not working on queried result.

while profiling I see high nano seconds during aggregation

```
"aggregations" : [
          {
            "type" : "GlobalOrdinalsStringTermsAggregator",
            "description" : "users",
            "time_in_nanos" : 91737162,
            "breakdown" : {
              "reduce" : 0,
              "build_aggregation_count" : 1,
              "post_collection" : 1878,
              "initialize_count" : 1,
              "reduce_count" : 0,
              "collect_count" : 5,
              "post_collection_count" : 1,
              "build_leaf_collector" : 15302476,
              "build_aggregation" : 76398285,
              "build_leaf_collector_count" : 28,
              "initialize" : 23555,
              "collect" : 10968
            },
            "debug" : {
              "segments_with_multi_valued_ords" : 0,
              "collection_strategy" : "dense",
              "segments_with_single_valued_ords" : 28,
              "deferred_aggregators" : [
                "raf"
              ],
              "total_buckets" : 9942540,
              "built_buckets" : 1,
              "result_strategy" : "terms",
              "has_filter" : false
            },
```

Any help would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `userId` field has high cardinality (it's an identifier, after all), my guess is that the performance of your `terms` aggregation is impaired by the calculation of the global ordinals for that field ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eager-global-ordinals.html#_what_are_global_ordinals)). The higher the cardinality of a field, the more resources/time are needed to calculate global ordinals.

You can find the recommendations from Elastic to handle these cases in the docs I linked above, basically:

- enabling `eager_global_ordinals` as opposed to the default lazy loading --> you won't have performance issues at query time because you go through the computation effort at index time (whose performance will be affected, though)
- disabling global ordinals altogether at the expense of higher memory use and of losing their benefits in your sub-aggregation "raf"

Final important note: you're using the `must` compound query for filtering, I would recommend you use the more performant and appropriate `filter` compound query ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)) (or even a Filter aggregation - [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html))

Answer (score 0):

To tune the high cardinality field search you can use [mapper murmur3 plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-murmur3.html)

> The mapper-murmur3 plugin provides the ability to compute hash of
> field values at index-time and store them in the index. This can
> sometimes be helpful when running cardinality aggregations on
> high-cardinality and large string fields.